# GitHub Ruby API - Update pull request description

Tags: ruby, github, jira, github-api

I'm using the following github ruby api: https://github.com/peter-murach/github
I'm trying to update a pull requests' description but the documentation doesn't seem to give any idea as to how to do this.
Here is my code so far:

```
def link_github_jira
    github = Github.new basic_auth: 'user:pass'
    @github_jira = github.pull_requests.list '<Name>', '<reposity_name>', state: 'open'
    @github_data = []
    @issues      = []

    @github_jira.each do | x |
      @github_data << x
    end

    @github_data.each do | x | 
      pull_id = x["title"].to_i 
      @pull_request_description = x["body"]
      if pull_id.is_a?(Integer) 
        uri = URI.parse("http://<jira_url>/rest/api/2/issue/#{pull_id}")
        http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
        http.use_ssl = true
        http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
        request.basic_auth '<jira_user>', '<jira_pass>'
        request["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
        @jira_response = http.request(request)
        @issues << JSON.parse(@jira_response.body)
        if !@pull_request_description.include?("<jira_url>") 
            #add Jira link to pull description as it does not already exist 
        end
      end 
    end
  end
```

Does any have any ideas as to how I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by using this GitHub Ruby API instead: https://github.com/pengwynn/octokit

It's possible to update pull requests by using the following code:

```
client.update_pull_request("<repository>", <pull_id>, <pull_title>, <pull_description>, <pull_state>)
```